# Determining a point on the Yin Yang

Tags: c++, visual-c++, console

I have to invent an algorithm which when we enter two coordinates (x,y) in the console the result to be if the point with that coordinates lay in the black part of picture either white or on the border. If you can help me would be great.

[image]

I started with the smallest circles and do that but I have no idea how to continue.

```
     double x;
     double y;

     const int smallCircleRadius = 1;
     const int mediumCircleRadius = 3;
     const int bigCircleRadius = 6;

     cin >> x >> y;

    double d1 = sqrt(pow(abs(x - 0),2) + pow(abs(y - 3),2));
    double d2 = sqrt(pow(abs(x - 0),2) + pow(abs(y + 3),2));
    if(d1 < smallCircleRadius)
    {
        cout<<"Evil";
    }
    else if(d2 < smallCircleRadius)
    {
        cout<<"Good";
    }
    if(d1 == smallCircleRadius || d2 == smallCircleRadius)
    {
        cout<<"Neutral";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the logic figured out, in python, so you'll have to port it, but you'll get the idea:

```
smallCircleRadius = 1
mediumCircleRadius = 3
bigCircleRadius = 6

def yytest(x,y):
    print(x,y,)

    in_big_circle = ((x**2)+(y**2)) < bigCircleRadius**2

    in_small_circle_upper_y = x**2+(y-mediumCircleRadius)**2 < smallCircleRadius**2
    in_small_circle_lower_y = x**2+(y+mediumCircleRadius)**2 < smallCircleRadius**2

    in_medium_circle_upper_y = x**2+(y-mediumCircleRadius)**2 < mediumCircleRadius**2
    in_medium_circle_lower_y = x**2+(y+mediumCircleRadius)**2 < mediumCircleRadius**2

    in_left_quadrant = x < 0

    if in_big_circle:
        if in_left_quadrant:
            if (not in_medium_circle_lower_y or in_small_circle_lower_y) and not in_small_circle_upper_y:
                return("good")
            else:
                return("evil")
        else:
            # right quadrant
            if (not in_medium_circle_upper_y or in_small_circle_upper_y) and not in_small_circle_lower_y:
                return("evil")
            else:
                return("good")

    else:
        return("neutral")

print(yytest(1,1))     # good
print(yytest(10,10))   # neutral
print(yytest(-0.5,3))  # evil
print(yytest(2,-2))  # evil
```

basically you have to compute flags about point in or not in the circles, then the quadrant (left or right) and combine the flags. The drawing helps a lot here :)

Comment: Thank you! I got the logic 
partially but that symbol '**' and '<' here `in_small_circle_upper_y = x**2+(y-mediumCircleRadius)**2 < smallCircleRadius**2` for example what means because I do not know Python at all?

Comment: `**2` is square. I don't use square root, I compare the squared distance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you would do it in C++.  That is, if your assignment called for dumping ASCII art instead of this "good" and "evil" thing.  But it will be trivial to adapt `GetYyZone` to your needs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// GetYyZone returns the color corresponding to a point:
// +1 for one color, -1 for its opposite and 0 for points outside the figure
int GetYyZone(double x, double y, double radius=6) {
    // Calculate sub-radii
    const double med_radius = radius / 2;     // always half the major radius
    const double sm_radius  = med_radius / 3; // anything smaller than the medium radius

    // check for points outside the main disk, returing 0 if so.
    if(x*x + y*y > radius*radius) return 0;

    // d_xl_sq is the squared distance from the point to its sub-center
    const double d_xl_sq = x*x + y*y - std::fabs(y)*med_radius*2 + med_radius*med_radius;
    if(d_xl_sq < sm_radius*sm_radius)   return y > 0 ? -1 :  1;
    if(d_xl_sq < med_radius*med_radius) return y > 0 ?  1 : -1;
    return x > 0 ? -1 : 1;
}

int main() {
    // This calls GetYyZone to select characters for ASCII art
    const int cols = 75;
    const int rows = 36;
    for(int j=0; j<rows; ++j) {
        for(int i=0; i<cols; ++i) {
            const double x = (2.0/(cols - 1) * i - 1) * 6.5;
            const double y = (2.0/(rows - 1) * j - 1) * -6.5;
            const int zone = GetYyZone(x, y);
            std::cout << (zone == 0 ? '+' : zone == -1 ? '#' : ' ');
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                ###++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++                          #####++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++                               ######+++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++                                    #######++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++                                       ########++++++++++++++
++++++++++++                       #####              #########++++++++++++
++++++++++                       #########            ###########++++++++++
++++++++                        ###########            ############++++++++
+++++++                         ###########            #############+++++++
++++++                           #########            ###############++++++
+++++                               ###               ################+++++
+++++                                                #################+++++
++++                                                ###################++++
++++                                              #####################++++
+++                                            #########################+++
+++                                        #############################+++
+++                             ########################################+++
+++                         ############################################+++
++++                     ##############################################++++
++++                   ################################################++++
+++++                 ################################################+++++
+++++                ###############   ###############################+++++
++++++               ############         ###########################++++++
+++++++             ############           #########################+++++++
++++++++            ############           ########################++++++++
++++++++++           ############         #######################++++++++++
++++++++++++         ##############     #######################++++++++++++
++++++++++++++        #######################################++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++       ####################################++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++      ###############################+++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++     ##########################++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   ################++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```